# Highstock - how to shift the X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have the following chart here:

[image]

what I'd like to do is shift the X axis so that the path only reaches the half of the width and the rest is blank (planning to put some plotlines there of some future events) - any ideas how to do it? Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you simply need to give your x axis a `max` property.

> #### `max`: Number
>
> The maximum value of the axis. If null, the max value is automatically calculated. If the endOnTick option is true, the max value might be rounded up.
>
> – [xAxis.max - Highstock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.max)

They give a demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/min-max/

In your case, if you're wanting your current data to end half way along the x axis, you need to set the `max` to the difference between where the data starts and where the data currently ends on top of the point the data currently ends.

As you haven't specified any code yourself, I'm going to use dummy values. If your x axis data starts at 5 and ends at 8, the difference between 5 and 8 is 3, so you need to add that to 8 to offset the chart:

```
xAxis: {
  max: 11 // (8 - 5 + 8)
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your quick answer but the thing is in my case the min and max data are being changed dynamically as there is constantly new data coming in, so the x axis so I don't really have concrete values for min and max. 

In my code, the place where I have the chart defined there is a redraw event so I tried updating the max value there but it didn't affect it. I'm not sure where would be the best place to set it in this case. :?